# How does the Price Trends feature in eBay work in IE?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, cross-browser

When looking at a listing for eBay, for example:

http://catalog.ebay.com/Apple-iPod-classic-5th-Generation-Black-30-GB-/60655662?_pcatid=39&_refkw=ipod&_trkparms=65%253A12%257C66%253A2%257C39%253A1%257C72%253A4030&_trksid=p3286.c0.m14

The Price Trends chart shows up as `iframe` apparently using HTML 5 canvas. But IE does not support canvas element but still it shows up correctly in IE. How does it works in IE? Also it appears the `src` attribute of iframe is empty but there is HTML content within the iframe. How is this happening?

But my main question is how it is working in IE?

Comment: Maybe there's some javascript that manipulates the DOM?

Comment: Let me know if this gets closed, I'll vote to reopen

Comment: Ping @Pekka. Still don't understand why someone might want to close this

Comment: So the reason it doesn't have a src on load is because that value is set dynamically, most likely so they can send get parameters to the page. Yes it could be hardcoded, but why not make things reusable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It uses a charting library called [jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/). 
If presented to IE this calls it's excanvas script

Example of which is here 
[Excanvas](http://www.jqplot.com/excanvas.js)

Comment: Almost, but not quite there - the most important part here is that excanvas uses Microsoft's propreitary VML technology to emulate canvas on IE.